# How can I have a second figure in one chapter instead of commas?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, bugs

While writing my thesis i encountered this annoying problem/bug.

When I place **two** figures each with a tikzpicture in one chapter, I get commas (,, ,,,,) in the pdf, spread over two pages instead of the second figure.
Latex runs without error.

[image: Faulty pdf with commas instead of second figure]

Thesis.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

% Define typearea
% a) Use automatic:
\usepackage[BCOR=1cm]{typearea}
% b) Or use fixed: 
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{left=1.5cm,textwidth=18.5cm,top=1.5cm,textheight=26.5cm}

% Use German :
\usepackage[german, USenglish]{babel}
% Use list of tabels, etc. in table of contents:
\usepackage{tocbibind}
% German paragraph skip
\usepackage{parskip}
% Encoder:????
%\usepackage[utf-8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Use A4-paper efficiently:
\usepackage{a4wide}
% Index-generation
\usepackage{makeidx}
% Einbinden von URLs:
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
% Special \LaTex symbols (e.g. \BibTeX):
\usepackage{doc}
% Include Graphic-files:
%\usepackage{graphics}
% Include Graphic-files:
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Include doc++ generated tex-files:
%\usepackage{docxx}
% Include PDF links
%\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% Include PDF links
%\usepackage[hidelinks, pdftex, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% OTHER SETTINGS:

% Pagestyle:
\pagestyle{headings}

% Avoid 'overhang':
\sloppy

% Choose language
\newcommand{\setlang}[1]{\selectlanguage{#1}\nonfrenchspacing}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% TITLE:

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\begin{center}
        {\bf\Huge Master‘s Thesis} 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
        \settowidth{\baselineskip}{0.4cm}
        {\LARGE 
        Something Something
        }
\end{center}

\vfill
\chapter{TEST}

Hi, this test.

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node at (0,0) {text1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{this shows something.}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node at (0,0) {text2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{this shows something else.}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Tex output:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `Thesis' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error    -interaction=nonstopmode Thesis.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/USenglish.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocbibind/tocbibind.sty

Package tocbibind Note: Using chapter style headings, unless overridden.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/a4wide/a4wide.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntgclass/a4.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/makeidx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/doc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.coltype.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./Thesis.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into your preamble.
 on input line 63.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Chapter 1.
[2] [3]
Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [4]
(./Thesis.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl12.pfb>
Output written on Thesis.pdf (4 pages, 41633 bytes).
Transcript written on Thesis.log.

TeX Output finished at Wed Oct 13 15:28:04
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the commas, but one figure is at bottom of chapter page and second is centered in second page. This result is quite normal. I don't know about report class, but some classes don't place figure in chapter's initial page. In general, don't worry about figures position until you have almost finished the text of your document.

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks for your comment! There is a lot of text and other figures around there already.  I just removed them so that the problem comes out more clearly. Also positioning is not something that i care about at the moment, all i want is the figure to show up. I am glad to hear that this example is working for you. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Try deleting the Thesis.aux file.  Bad aux files sometimes prevent a new aux file from being created, so the only way to get rid of them is to manually delete them.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the tip, unfortunately that wasn't it.